# Trying to enable sound on incoming SMS in Flex Twilio

Tags: javascript, function, twill

I've set up a workspace in Flex to handle incoming SMS contacts from customers. What I'm trying to do is enable an audio notification that a new SMS message has come into Flex. I'm working on a Flex Plugin to do this.

What I've done is added a listener for a new reservation being created. 
If a new reservation has been created I'm trying to play an audio file as the notification. I've enabled error logging but the code is not triggering any errors.

```
    init(flex, manager) {
    let ringer = new Audio("*.mp3");
    ringer.loop = true;

     const resStatus = ["accepted","rejected","rescinded","timeout"];
     manager.workerClient.on("reservationCreated", function(reservation) {
if (reservation.task.taskChannelUniqueName === 'sms') {
  ringer.play()
};
    resStatus.forEach((e) => {
    reservation.on(e, () => {
    ringer.pause()'''
```

I was expecting the mp3 to play if a new reservation was created with a taskchanneldefinition name of sms. New sms messages come into the sms channel. When running on Flex, no sound plays and no errors are being logged.

Answer (score 0):

try playing sounds outside this method, does it work?
a few possible problems that you may face:

1) new Audio("*.mp3"), do you load a sound here properly? i think something is wrong with this one

if not

2) you likely need to interact with flex-ui as said herehttps://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/audio-player#troubleshooting

here is an example that i have and it works:

```
manager.chatClient.on("messageAdded", () => {
  //some stuff going on here

   new Audio(NEW_MESSAGE_AUDIO).play();
});
```

where NEW_MESSAGE_AUDIO is a `data:audio/mpeg;base64` file